# Brakes dragging 1998 CB600F Hornet

Tags: motorcycle, brakes, binding

I have an issue with my front left brake dragging on my 1998 Hornet.
I'm trying to sort it but I'm baffled.

I can visually see that the pistons retract once I release the brake lever. The caliper has been rebuilt(new seals and new pistons).

I have replaced the front wheel bearings as they were notchy. When I go to spin the wheel by hand I get maybe 1/4 revolution and the scraping sound. I can hear this scraping when riding and when I'm pushing the bike.

If I remove the left caliper and push the bike I hear an acceptable light scrape from the other caliper which leads me to believe the left is the problem.

1. The slide pins are greased
2. The pistons retract when lever is released
3. It's tough to push pistons in by hand(res cap on so the pressure making it hard?)
4. New pistons
5. New seals
6. New pads
7. Brake discs rust very easily but are within spec.

I'm out of ideas, it didn't have the issue when I got the bike a few months ago but the old pistons were scored and rusty, the pads had less than 1mm on them so the work needed to be done.

What could cause the issue? MOT is due soon and I'm out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated.

I would rather it not go the garage as this is my daily commuter.

Comment: I'm also ruling out the master cylinder as surely this would affect both brakes I assume.

Comment: I am not familiar with this specific model. But your point #3 suggests the possibility that the brake system vent is blocked. Air must be able to escape as the fluid level rises in the system (which happens when the pads retract, for example). Usually there's a small passageway from the pressure side of the master cylinder bore; the passageway is covered by the master cylinder piston when the piston moves to apply the brakes. If the passageway (maybe only a mm or two across) is blocked, pressure in the system cannot be relieved.

Comment: That's the small hole in the master cylinder right? With the res cap off I can see a small bubble come from it when pulling the lever slowly. Is too much brake fluid a possibility? Also I've noticed the left fork is .6mm higher than the right fork in the top tripple. Could that be a contributing factor? cheers

Comment: That’s the hole, and a bubble shows it isn’t blocked. Too much fluid s not a problem. So....sorry, I’m out of ideas.

Comment: No worries, cheers for your input. I have lowered that fork slightly(it was .6mm higher than the other before) and it seems to have made a difference. That and cleaning the disc with some brake cleaner and 800grit sandpaper I can now get over a full revolution and can't hear the scraping when pushing. A proper ride will let me know if that's solved the issue so fingers crossed.